# Is there any open sourced android voice recognition application available?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Is there any open sourced android voice recognition application available? If available then please give the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx 3.5 is an open source voice app for android developed by a university. It might come in handy for u. [Open Source Voice Recognition App](http://www.androidtech.com/html/speech-recognition-free-softwa.php)